# How do I incorporate an innovative outlier at observation 48 in my ARIMA model?

Tags: r, time-series, arima, outliers

I am working on a data set. After using some model identification techniques, I came out with an ARIMA(0,2,1) model.

I used the `detectIO` function in the package `TSA` in R to detect an *innovative* outlier (IO) at the 48th observation of my original data set.

How do I incorporate this outlier into my model so I can use it for forecasting purposes? I don't want to use the ARIMAX model since I might not be able to make any predictions from that in R. Are there any other ways I could do this?

Here are my values in order:

```
VALUE <- scan()
  4.6  4.5  4.4  4.5  4.4  4.6  4.7  4.6  4.7  4.7  4.7  5.0  5.0  4.9  5.1  5.0  5.4
  5.6  5.8  6.1  6.1  6.5  6.8  7.3  7.8  8.3  8.7  9.0  9.4  9.5  9.5  9.6  9.8 10.0
  9.9  9.9  9.8  9.8  9.9  9.9  9.6  9.4  9.5  9.5  9.5  9.5  9.8  9.3  9.1  9.0  8.9
  9.0  9.0  9.1  9.0  9.0  9.0  8.9  8.6  8.5  8.3  8.3  8.2  8.1  8.2  8.2  8.2  8.1
  7.8  7.9  7.8  7.8
```

That is actually my data. They are unemployment rates over a period of 6 years. There are 72 observations then . Each value is to at most one decimal place

Comment: @Jonsca: Thanks for the nice editing. I wish i could do same.

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: You can create a dummy that's 1 for $t=48$ and 0 at all other periods. Then re-estimate the model. That will keep this outlier from skewing up the forecast. If that's not what you have in mind, you should elaborate on the second paragraph.

Comment: @ Dimitriy V. Masterov: Could you explain the process of your first paragraph again? Now, my question again: After specifying a tentative ARIMA(0,2,1) model, i do a diagnostic test to determine the fitness of the model . This model then identifies an IO. But I would have to add-up this outlier into my model before i can use it for forecasting.  My question was, how do i go about that?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still have no idea what that means. I meant that you might re-stimate the ARIMA(0,2,1) with the dummy variable.

Comment: Okay. How would i be able to create the dummy? Could you help me with an R-code that helps me set up the dummy variable?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov: are you able to help me with an R-Code to create that dummy? thanks. i just need an R-code to set up a model for : arima(0,2,1) with IO=48

Comment: I believe it's just `dummy <- as.numeric(period == 48)` if your time variable is named period. Then you include dummy as one of your covariates.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Would that approach work for an innovation outlier?

Comment: @Glen_b  No it eould not. What my friend D. suggested would only work for an AO. Since an IO is functionally relatable to an IO via the ARIMA process it might be possible to create a sequence of 1's (covariates) in the manner D suggested.

Comment: @Glen_b If I is for innovational, then this will not work. I saw influencial and thought detectAO. Mea culpa.

Comment: @b2amen Second differencing tends to make me worry a bit. How long is the series? What does the series and the ACF/PACF look like after second differencing?

Comment: @Glen_b: My original data have 72 observations. I used the Augmented Dicker Fuller Test to test at each stage to make sure I was dealing with a stationary data. It was only my second difference which turned out to be stationary.  For my second difference, my ACF had a significant lag at lag 1. my pacf kinda died down/out

Comment: @b2amen Is there any chance that the data - the original series with 72 observations - could be shared with us and be included in the question body?

Comment: Would a repeated application of what I suggested, yielding a set of dummies, work in this case?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Yes .

Comment: @Gen_b You are correct , it should disturb you as this is probably over differenced yielding a cancelling MA(1). Misidentification results from using inappropriate tools.

Comment: Note that your model identification will be affected by your outlier. OP you haven't been very responsive to the many comments and questions that have been made.

Comment: @Glen_b: above is my data. I Hope that could assist you in assisting me. Thanks a lot

Comment: In the second differences, you have what looks like an outlier, but it's apparently caused by a small additive jump at observation 47 in the original series, which when differenced twice looks like a large negative outlier one period later. If you do something simple to remove that small effect at observation 47 (almost anything sensible), no outliers appear in the second difference. I'd say it's perhaps better looked at as an AO on the original scale.

Comment: @Glen_b: thanks for your response. when i use the "detectAO" function from R on my Arima(0,2,1) model, it detects no AO, but the "detectIO" detects an IO instead at observation 48. Do you think there might be something going on that i am not aware of?

Comment: There's a lot going on in this dataset, but the local temporal behavior (correlation, seasonality, etc) is the least of it. When you blindly analyze data like this as just a sequence of numbers, you are at risk of producing ridiculous results (or worse). What can you tell us about what these data *mean*? Are they perhaps measurements of something at a monitoring station? An economic time series? A chart of biological growth? Understanding something about the underlying phenomenon will usually do far more to help identify a model than any amount of fiddling with statistical software can.

Comment: @whuber: they are unemployment rates over a period of 6 years!

Comment: Thank you. That opens up a huge area of opportunities, doesn't it? After all, we know unemployment rates are driven by external economic forces.  We have records of some of them that explain why the period during the first three years or so probably should not be analyzed in the same way we would analyze the subsequent three years. Why, then, are you trying to make your forecast in a vacuum?

Comment: @whuber: forecast in a vacuum?

Comment: Before you edited your question, it said absolutely nothing about what these data mean: we had no context and no understanding of reasonable limits on their statistical behavior. That's a vacuum. Understanding now that these are unemployment data, it is evident that the forecast can be improved with external information, including other economic data indicating when the recession began and ended, information about the timing and amounts of government interventions, information about the numbers of people who simply have stopped looking for work or are only part-time employed, and so on.

Comment: @whuber: i think i now understand. Thanks for your willingness to help!

Comment: @b2amen If you *really* want to model this unemployment rate (it looks like the U.S.?) then it would be worth reading up on non-linear modelling economic time-series. A good source is [Nonlinear models in economic theory by Timo Teräsvirta, Dag Tjøstheim and W. J. Granger](http://oxfordindex.oup.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199587148.003.0002) As a first step, however, it would be advisable to refer to Tong's Non-linear time series analysis: A dynamic system approach (1990). The first chapter of Granger et al. contains a very informative section on modelling unemployment.

Comment: @Glen_b You will see in my response that I confirned your outlier at t=47 . Your very keen reflection that the double differening mistake yielded an outlier at the wring period, Very insightful of you and quite illuminating as the errors encountered as a result of miss-identification

Comment: The same data - and mention of its source - appears in [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32657/r-package-tsa-how-to-interpret-the-io-coefficients-output-of-the-arimax-functio)

Comment: @Glen_b while http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32657/r-package-tsa-how-to-interpret-the-io-coefficients-output-of-the-arimax-functio used 100 values and this post used 72 as the basis.

Comment: @IrishStat Ah, thanks; I hadn't checked the number of observations were the same.

Answer (score 3):

If

$$Y(t) = [\theta/\phi][A(t)+\text{IO}(t)]$$

then

$$Y^\text{*}(t) = [\theta/\phi][A(t)] + [\theta/\phi][\text{IO}(t)].$$

If

$$\theta = 1\ \ \text{and}\ \ \phi = [1-.5B]$$

for example ... then

$$Y^\text{*}(t) = [1/(1-.5B)][A(t)] \\  
\quad\quad\quad\quad+ \text{IO}(t) - .5\cdot \text{IO}(t-1) + .25\cdot \text{IO}(t-2) - .125\cdot \text{IO}(t-3)-\cdots\,.$$

If for example the estimate of the IO effect is $10.0$, then

$$Y^{*}(t) = [1/(1-.5B)][A(t)] \\
\quad\quad\quad\quad+ 10\cdot \text{IO}(t) - 5\cdot \text{IO}(t-1) + 2.5\cdot \text{IO}(t-2) - 1.25\cdot \text{IO}(t-3)-\cdots\,.$$
where the indicator variable for $\text{IO}$ is 0 or 1.

In this way you can see that the impact of the anomaly not only is instantaneous but has memory.

Software like AUTOBOX (which I am familiar with) does not identify IO effects (but rather AO effects) would identify a sequence of anomalies with values 10, -5, 2.5, -1.25,... starting at period $t$ .

The user upon seeing this rare event could restate the transfer between the AO intervention with a dynamic structure $[w(b)/d(b)]$ rather than a pure numerator structure $[w(b)]$ yielding the same result as if an IO effect was incorporated.

Anytime you incorporate memory, be it a result of a differencing operator or ARMA structure, it is a tacit admission of ignorance due to omitted causal series. This is also true of the need to incorporate Intervention deterministic series such as Pulses/Level Shifts, Seasonal Pulses or Local Time Trends. These dummy variables are a neede proxy for omitted determinstic user-specified causal variables. Oftentime all you have is the series of interest and given the qualifiers that I have spelled out, you can forecast the future based upon the past in total ignorance of exactly the nature of the data being analyzed. The only problem is you are using the rear-window to predict the road ahead ....a dangerous thing indeed. To stand up and declare the forecasts is based solely on the past of the series and some proxy ARIMA stuff and some proxy deterministic stuff is quite silly BUT in the absence of the knowledge of the true causals , it can be useful, As G.E.P.BOX said "all model are wrong, but some are useful"

after the data was posted ...

A reasonable model is a (1,1,0) is [image] and the AO anomalies were identified at periods 39,41,47,21 and 69 (not period 48) . The residuals from this model appear to be free of evident structure. [image] AND [image] The fice AO values an optimal representation of the activity reflected by activity not in the history of the time series. I would think that the ACF of the OP's over-differenced model would reflect model inadequacy. Here is the model. [image]  Again there is no R code delivered as the problem or opportunity is in the realm of model identification/revision/validation. Finally, a plot of the actual/fitted and forecasted series.

Comment: thanks for your reply; but i actually wanted an R-Code instead for my model.

Comment: @b2amen Yes I undersatnd BUT Glen_b wanted some "stuff" and I thought I would respond to him.

Comment: Thanks for the editing. You and I would make good partners !

Comment: @ IrishStat: my data is included in the original question. Hope that could assist you in assisting me. Thanks anyways

Comment: @IrishStat: I like your output. It looks pretty neat to me. And what software did you use? But could you explain how you identified an AR(2,1,0)? Thanks

Comment: b2amen My guess that IrishStat would have used AUTOBOX as mentioned in his answer.

Comment: David, I removed the comment that contained personal contact information. You're free to put that in your profile, but such solicitations are not welcome directly on our site, as you know.

Comment: @WHUBER ok I was just responding to a request for more details that I felt was a bit much to post.

Comment: Generally the best response to a request for more (on-topic) details - when that is beyond what you'd put up in an answer or comment - is, where feasible\*, to take it to chat. $\quad$ \*(100 rep. points to create a chat room, 20 to talk in chat; no need to both be on at the same time)